# Can we make Data list Autocomplete to search both on text and value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a requirement where i want a auto complete input text in which user can search the Currency based on both text value and currency code. 
For example : When user type USD / United States Dollar it should display "United States Dollar".

I tried giving value as "USD" and text as "United States Dollar" to datalist, but it did not work.

Is there anyway to do it ?

Thanks

**HTML**

```
<input type="search" id="ajax" list="json-datalist" placeholder="Base Currency">
<datalist id="json-datalist">
  <option value="USD">United States Dollar</option>
  <option value="INR">Indian Rupee</option>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Twitter's `typehead.js` plugin](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) instead. It can be customized exactly as you want.

Checkout the demo on its homepage.